# Why did Meliodas say to Percival that they need him?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In an episode of The Four Knights of the Apocalypse, Meliodas told Percival that they needed. Why the remaining 7 deadly sins, would need him and the other 4 knights of the Apocalypse? Are the 4 Knights of the Apocalypse supposed to surpass the 7 deadly sins or something?